# How to make GStreamer pipeline work using gi.repository in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer-1.0, v4l2, python-gstreamer, deepstream

this is my first time asking a question here.

I'm trying to create a GStreamer pipeline using the `gi.repository` from Python3. I want to make it this way instead of using `deepstream-app` or `gst-launch-1.0` application because in the future I want to use Nvidia modules and execute a DNN to detect objects in the streaming video and I think that this way it will be easier to extract the metadata from the DNN inference.

Looking around I found this pipeline:

`v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse config-interval=3 ! qtmux ! filesink location=video.mp4`

It works perfect and create a .mp4 file from the video of my USB webcam when I execute it using `gst-launch-1.0` application or using the the function `Gst.parse_launch("pipeline")` from Gst in `gi.repository`.

But when I try to make the pipeline creating each element individually and linking them in a Python code, I can't make it work. It creates a .mp4 file of size around 1 MB, althougth I can't reproduce it. It returns the error `0xc00d36c4` in the Video app from Windows10 and nothing with VLC.
It may be something related to the muxer element (qtmux or mp4mux), because I have seen other [example](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_python_apps/blob/master/apps/deepstream-test1-usbcam/deepstream_test_1_usb.py) that links the sink of the muxer to the source of the previous element in the pipeline. It has something to do with dinamic pads, but I don't really understand when they are necessary.

I will leave parts of my code here, so you can guide me where the problem is. The time I tried to link the source of the parse with the sink of the muxer is commented, beacuse I get the same result without doing it.

The imports.

```py
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gst
import time
import pyds
```

The creation of the pipeline and its elements.

```py
Gst.init(None)
player=Gst.Pipeline.new("player")
print("Pipeline created")

v4l2Source=Gst.ElementFactory.make("v4l2src","v4l2Source")
v4l2Source.set_property("device", "/dev/video0")
print("USB cam source created")

caps = Gst.Caps.from_string("video/x-raw")
filter= Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "filter")
filter.set_property("caps", caps)

videoconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "converter")

encoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("x264enc","venc")

parser=Gst.ElementFactory.make("h264parse","parser")
parser.set_property("config-interval", 3)

muxer=Gst.ElementFactory.make("mp4mux","muxer")

filesink=Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink","sinker")
filesink.set_property("location","pvideo.mp4")

print("All elements created")

i=0
for ele in [v4l2Source,filter,videoconvert,encoder,parser,muxer,filesink]:
print(f"Element {i} added to the pipeline")
player.add(ele)
i+=1
print("All Elements added to the pipeline")
```

The linking of every element. **The error is probably in this part.** As I mentioned before, the pipeline works if executed with `gst-launch-1.0` or `Gst.parse_launch("pipeline")` .

```py
v4l2Source.link(filter)
filter.link(videoconvert)
videoconvert.link(encoder)
encoder.link(parser)

'''
sinkpad = muxer.get_request_pad("video_0")
if not sinkpad:
sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get the sink pad of streammux \n")
srcpad = parser.get_static_pad("src")
if not srcpad:
sys.stderr.write(" Unable to get source pad of caps_vidconvsrc \n")

srcpad.link(sinkpad)
'''
parser.link(muxer)
muxer.link(filesink)
print("All elements linked")
```

And at last, the execution and stop of the pipeline. It records for around 20 seconds of footage before stopping the record.

```py
player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
print("Recording")
time.sleep(20) 
print('Sending EOS')
player.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
print('Waiting for EOS')
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

@mo_oises

Your code looks good! Just one thing left to make the GStreamer pipeline work using the Gi Repository in Python3, as per your request. You need to consider waiting for the EOS (End of Stream) signal from the GStreamer bus before closing the application. This can be achieved using the [timed_pop_filtered(timeout, types)](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gst-1.0/classes/Bus.html#Gst.Bus.timed_pop_filtered) method of the GStreamer bus.

For instance, appending this to your code resolves the issue:

```py
EOS_TIMEOUT_NS = 3_000_000_000
bus = player.get_bus()
if bus.timed_pop_filtered(EOS_TIMEOUT_NS, Gst.MessageType.EOS) is None:
    raise RuntimeError("Pipeline did not receive EOS message within the timeout period")

if player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL) == Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE:
    raise ValueError("Unable to stop the pipeline")
```

Cheers,
-- Daniel

Comment: Thank you so much, that helps me a lot.
Trying your solution I also found, that If you don't know how much time you have been recording, instead of EOS_TIMEOUT_NS, you can use Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE and the function timed_pop_filtered will just wait until it recieve the EOS message.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, this answer also helps me a lot.  Can you shed light on the value to set for the timeout parameter EOS_TIMEOUT_NS?  Does 3_000_000_000 work in all instances regardless of the length of the recording?